# How do I use an if statement with a returned bool function?

Tags: c++, function, return, boolean

I'm sort of confused on how to return bool values. Basically I need to make a program to check and see if a number is either prime or not. I think I have, for the most part, the right idea, but I'm not quite sure how I'd use an if statement depending on whether or not the bool function returns true or false.Thanks guys

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

bool isPrime(int);
void main()
{
    int InNumber;
    cout << "Enter a number to check if it is prime or not." << endl;
    cin >> InNumber;
    isPrime(InNumber);
    if (isPrime())
    {
        cout << "number is prime." << endl;
    }
}

bool isPrime(int Check)
{
    for (int i = 2; i < Check; i++)
    {
        if (Check % 88 == 0)
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    }
 }
```

Comment: Just put `isPrime(InNumber)` in your if condition.

Comment: Note that your `IsPrime` implementation is incorrect. (if it was for minimal code, you might use `isOdd()`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store the resulting value in a variable, that will be used in the test condition:

```
bool isPrimeResult = isPrime(InNumber);
if (isPrimeResult)
{
    cout << "number is prime." << endl;
}
```

Or directly use the resulting value in the test:

```
if (isPrime(InNumber))
{
    cout << "number is prime." << endl;
}
```

The first approach is recommended if you have to reuse the returned value many times in the code. The second one is the most recommended in your own case (you just need that value there, so the assignment is "useless").

Comment: The variable name `isPrime` and function name `isPrime()` cannot be same. :)

Comment: @user1336087: Ahahaha, thank you! I got confused with Java (that I use daily, now)...I have to refresh my C++ basics :D

Comment: Thanks a ton. Was tired af last night, posted this and went to bed. Nice to wake up too. Helped me solve my problem :p